# Google distance Matrix in Stata

Tags: google-maps, stata

I used the *traveltime* instruction (together with *geocode*) in Stata, that, by the use of Google distance matrix, it calculates the distance and the travel time between two points (origin and destination). I have no problems with the code, everything works perfectly, but the problem is that I can not figure out if this procedure taking into account the curvature of the earth (such as happens, for example, using the Haversine formula). Could you help me to understand what type of formula is used? Also I suppose that with this instruction we consider a path actually viable and not just theoretical (such as the presence of a mountain, sea ..), is it true?
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: The distance and travel time calculations are done at Google's end. These Stata programs are just ways of getting Google to do the work and report back. You can see for yourself what the Stata programs do by using (e.g.) `viewsource traveltime.ado` in Stata, and it's less than you think.

Answer (score 1):

`traveltime3` (and all its ancestors that work with previous versions of the Google API) uses Google's guess for the best driving/walking/biking distance along some viable route at a point in time. The meaning of best is [pretty fuzzy](http://google-latlong.blogspot.com/2009/05/would-you-like-some-extra-suggestions.html):

> Deciding which route is "best" involves balancing competing factors:
>   distance, travel time, number of turns, and many more. We boil all
>   these factors down to a "cost" associated with each candidate route
>   and display the route with the lowest "cost."

Biking directions seem to adjust for elevation [in picking the route](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2010/03/aint-no-mountain-high-enough.html) (though that does not mean the distance is adjusted for it). In [another blog post](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2007/11/road-to-better-path-finding.html), they link to the Wiki entry for [Dijkstra's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) when explaining how they pick the best route. So given some maps, historical and real time data from various sources such cell phones, their algorithm picks the best route using a black box method.

You can also calculate the length of the shortest curve between two points along the surface of a *mathematical model* of the earth. There seem to be two models in use. The Haversine formula calculates the approximate *great-circle* distance between two points, which is the shortest distance over the earth’s surface. This gives an ‘as-the-lazy-crow-flies’ distance between the points (ignoring the distance needed to go over any mountains or canyons on the way and assuming the earth is a sphere). The other method is to use the Vincenty equations (which is an slower, iterative process, but still assumes away terrain). Both methods can be used in Stata using `geodist` from ssc (which has a great help file with references). **As far as I know, there's no way to apply either method to an actual physical route to adjust for curvature.**

Here's an example that calculates the distance from the Bigfoot Discovery Museum in Felton, CA to Stata Corp HQ in College Station:

```
clear
set obs 1
gen to = "5497+State+Route+9,+Felton,+CA+95018"
gen from = "4905+Lakeway+Drive+College+Station,+Texas+77845"
traveltime3, start(from) end(to) units(imperial)
list t_distance, clean noobs
geocode3, address(to) fulladdress 
rename (g_lon g_lat) (lon1 lat1)
drop g_*
geocode3, address(from) fulladdress 
rename (g_lon g_lat) (lon2 lat2)
drop g_*
geodist lat1 lon1 lat2 lon2, miles gen(distance_h) sphere
geodist lat1 lon1 lat2 lon2, miles gen(distance_v)
list distance*, clean noobs
```

As you can see when you run the code, the travel distance (along Interstate 10) is ~1,838 miles, which you can verify with [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!data=!1m4!1m3!1d7473149!2d-109.1588835!3d33.773945!4m26!3m22!1m5!1sBigfoot+Discovery+Museum,+5497+State+Route+9,+Felton,+CA+95018!2s0x808e46afd7653329:0xc4b4eac4acb420a7!3m2!3d37.041607!4d-122.072594!1m5!1sStataCorp+LP,+4905+Lakeway+Dr,+College+Station,+TX+77845!2s0x86469aaf9feaad09:0x495dae11ffcd9445!3m2!3d30.552982!4d-96.245173!3m8!1m3!1d7473149!2d-109.1588835!3d33.773945!3m2!1i1680!2i845!4f13.1!4i1!5m2!13m1!1e1&fid=0). The Haversine distance is much shorter at 1,544 miles, so is the Vincenty one at 1,546 miles. You can verify that Stata is doing the math correctly and see a map of that route [here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) and [here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-vincenty.html), after you enter the lats and lons you get from `traveltime3`. For most uses, the Haversine approximation is sufficient (more on that at the last two links).